# Jquery Autocomplete from an Array in Session

Tags: jquery, vb.net, session, autocomplete

I will be storing an array in session that will contain data entered by the user (id numbers used to search in several different areas of the application)

I then want to return the values in this array that is residing in session as auto complete selections.

Getting the array into session and updating it is the easy part, getting it from session into the autocomplete isn't as much so.

I'd rather use the array to do the auto complete instead of converting to json.

I've tried using `'<%= SESSION("MEMBER_SEARCH_ARRAY") %>'` as the source for the autocomplete but no dice.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "../ajax/MemberAuto.ashx",
     dataType: "text",
     success: function(data) { 
          $('#txtDealerNumber').autoComplete({ source: data }); // <- Object doesn't support this property or method error
     },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) { }
});
```

when MemberAuto.ashx contains:

```
Public Class MemberAuto : Implements IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState, IReadOnlySessionState

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        context.Response.Write(Join(context.Session("MEMBER_SEARCH_ARRAY"), ","))
        context.Response.End()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

unfortunately I get an error following the ajax call in the success.

Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ive updated a couple of things... and the return from the ashx now returns a comma deliminated string... but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: what about the [ ]? using jqueryUI. right?

Comment: yes.  if I return it as a string it returns as a string... but autocomplete assumes that if its a string it is a remote call... if i return it as an array it is an object, and not a javascript array which the autocomplete is looking for

Comment: but why are using autocomplete it inside ajax? can't you initialize it earlier in document ready? my answer didn't worked?

Comment: what about Edit1? i think you need to use eval() function for manual ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using jQueryUI(seems like autocomplete is not a part of jQuery core), This can be easily implemented in this way. No need of ajax as `autocomplete` automatically does this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtDealerNumber").autocomplete({
            source: '../ajax/MemberAuto.ashx?AutoComplete'
        }); //function name is autocomplete not autoComplete
 });
```

where the url `../ajax/MemberAuto.ashx?AutoComplete`
returns(test it in the browser) in the format

```
["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
```

see here for more details.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source

**Edit1:** If you really want to stick in your way. then you need to convert your string to array which can be done using `eval()`.

ie.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "../ajax/MemberAuto.ashx",
     dataType: "text",
     success: function(data) { 
          $('#txtDealerNumber').autocomplete({ source: eval(data) }); 
          // data should be in the format ["option1", "option2"]
     },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) { }
});
```

for testing eval http://jsfiddle.net/wZkjZ/

Comment: ultimately you are correct.  i was able to get it working by changing a couple of things but i decided to scrap the entire thing and created my own auto complete due to the need to display more than simple data.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to achieve something like this, I always make my script (in your case memberauto.ashx) print javascript. In PHP for example, I use `print('var test = $test');`. Afterwards I use eval() to make javascript try to execute whatever the output of the page is. You can then use your new javascript variables / functions / whatever you've made in your ashx in your javascript. Plus, errors are easily catched when you wrap your eval() in try-catch.